# How to create symbolic link for Google Cloud SDK gcloud directory on a NAS drive?

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

The problem: we have several servers that need to reference the same Google Cloud SDK credentials and we want to reference those credentials from a central location. What is the easiest way to share these credentials between several servers?

What we tried: we tried to create soft and hard symbolic links to the gcloud directory but we did not have success, in both cases we received the following error message:

```
C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK> bq ls
WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\configurations\config_default].
ERROR: (bq) You do not currently have an active account selected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... use the below commands for the two files below to make a soft symbolic link to centralize credential files, not the gcloud directory itself:

mklink access_tokens.db

mklink credentials.db